# convert JSON object to a string

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to convert the json object to a string with special characters escaped.

following is the example

```
{
"xtype": "window",
"height": 250,
"width": 400,
"bodyPadding": "20 0 0 20",
"title": "Configuration",
"modal": true,
"items": [
    {
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Deploy Path"
    },
    {
        "xtype": "textfield",
        "fieldLabel": "Save Path"
    },
    {
        "xtype": "button",
        "margin": "20 0 0 100",
        "text": "Save"
    }
]
}
```

above object to

```
{\n    \"xtype\": \"window\",\n    \"height\": 250,\n    \"width\": 400,\n    \"bodyPadding\": \"20 0 0 20\",\n    \"title\": \"Configuration\",\n    \"modal\": true,\n    \"items\": [\n        {\n            \"xtype\": \"textfield\",\n            \"fieldLabel\": \"Deploy Path\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"xtype\": \"textfield\",\n            \"fieldLabel\": \"Save Path\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"xtype\": \"button\",\n            \"margin\": \"20 0 0 100\",\n            \"text\": \"Save\"\n        }\n    ]\n}
```

can anybody please help me here ?

Thanks in advance.

Hi,

My JSON contains some added plugins because of which the stringify function is not working. for example

```
plugins: [
Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
ptype: 'cellediting'
})
]
```

This is something where the things are not working for me , and i hope somebody can help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? -> JSON.parse ??? -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: This is not the same question. OP asks for escaping certain characters. Stop voting to close this question.

Comment: Also `JSON.parse` is completely wrong, `stringify` would be correct.

Comment: Are you trying to build a string literal to put in another program ?

Comment: Once again, this is not a duplicate. Learn to read people!

Comment: @GreenGuerilla : JSON.parse or JSON.stringify only converts the object to string and nothing else,

here i am looking for escaping the special chars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure of why you might want this. Is the goal to build a string literal that you could write in a program ?

But, anyway, this seems to do it :

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\n')
          .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
          .replace(/\n/g, '    ')
          .replace(/(?:[ ]{4}((?:[ ]{4})*))/g, '\\n$1');
```

Note that what you have to start with isn't a "JSON object" (which means nothing as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a data-exchange format) but a plain javascript object.

[*jsbin example*](http://jsbin.com/apeqej/2/edit?javascript,live)

Comment: I've altered the solution to what, I believe, is more closely to what OP is after. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @fireeyedboy No, I really don't mind. You're probably right (hard to be sure with OP not responding).

Comment: @destroy : yes , the goal here is to use the string in another program. 

i have already converted the JSON object to a string using JSON.stringify and then passing the converted string to a replace function. but i was not sure of a regex to use.
will use this and reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library:

here is one sample code.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
```

or

```
var j={"name":"phonetype"};
JSON.stringify(j); // '{"name":"phonetype"}'
```